# Angular Universal | How to stop animations from being played twice?

Tags: angular, animation, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm building a web application using Angular. 
For SEO purposes I have implemented SSR (Angular Universal).

Problem: When the application is fetched from the server various animations are played. 
A few seconds after (when browser rendering is complete and browser takes over) the same animations are played again.

This looks awful.

The animations in question are [ScrollReveal](https://github.com/scrollreveal/scrollreveal) and [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

**Question:** How can I prevent animations from being played a second time when browser rendering is complete?

Comment: I have the same issue, totally wired no answer to this.

Comment: the issue seems to be the fact that the dom elements are re-rendered when the js loads after the SSR has finished